# Python command to create no-arch rpm's

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools

I am creating rpm's for my project which is in pure python. I am running the command

> python setup.py bdist_rpm

to build the rpm. This is creating architechture specific rpm's (x86 or x86-64). What I would like is to have a no-arch rpm. Can any of python guru's help me with creating a no-arch rpm. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--force-arch` parameter, i.e.:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --force-arch noarch
```